# Sci-Fi book about traveling to another dimension where people (at a certain age) get put into a room and never come out

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

There was a 1950 sci-fi story in which a man travels to another dimension where, at a certain age, people get put into a room with a video screen and never come out. He has a love affair with a girl there, but she get put into a room.

Comment: Sound like the final scene of Soylent Green; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOV8mBjHHYg

Comment: If you're trying to edit your post please log in to the account and edit it. The following edit was rejected which may help people find the story: *There was a 1950's sci-fi story in which a man travels to another dimension where, at a certain age, people get put into a room to endlessly watch a video screen. They never come out and their bodies change. Their heads get big. The man has a love affair with a girl in this dimension, but she gets put into a room and he ends up snapping her neck.*